# Blur Effect using Swift language in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, swift

I've been trying to implement the blur effect using an UIImageView in xcode 6 (swift language), I'm trying to implement it so everything that is below the ImageView get blurred.

I cannot make it work, so I'm asking you guys from stack overflow to help me, please.

How can that be done?

the code I wrote so far is:

---

```
class blurImage: UIImageView {

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)

    }

}
```

---

Comment: Do you have working `Objective C` code ? If so, which part of transition exactly causes the problem ? If not, well, that might be quite a broad question then.

Comment: I don't have any working code... I was trying to do it in swift directly.

Comment: Then I recommend to find a solution working with Objective C as this  topic has already been discussed, then you try to write the same stuff with Swift. For example, you could use `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` and `UiView -addMotionEffect:` (available at iOs7+).

Comment: I'll do it! Thank you

Comment: @A-Live, As I know UIInterpolatingMotionEffect is not target for blur effect.It target for parallax effect

Comment: Yep, you can find some info about blur options available at iOs 8 at the new WWDC videos.

Answer (score 9):

You need to assign a frame to effect blur view  and add it as subview

> class blurImage: UIImageView {
>
> ```
> init(frame: CGRect) {
>     super.init(frame: frame)
>
>     var blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
>     var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
>     effectView.frame = frame
>     addSubview(effectView)
> }
>  }
> ```

Comment: How can I use this class with Storyboards?

Answer (score 2):

I modified @Kuroros class to work with Storyboards

```
class BlurImage: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
        var effectView:UIVisualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)
        effectView.frame = frame
        addSubview(effectView)
    }

}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldn’t the blur be a let rather than a var, seeing as it isn’t going to be modified?

Answer (score 0):

I modified @fabian implementation, because there is a problem with `frame` size calculation if you use auto-layout. When you try to read `frame` data in `init()` it's not properly calculated yet and have size (1000,1000) for me, while should be (420,420). So you need read and set later. I used `layoutSubviews` for it. Also settings `frame = frame` didn't worked, because it returns absolute container position, but we need box size.

```
class BluredImage: UIImageView {

    var effectView:UIVisualEffectView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        let blur:UIBlurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        effectView = UIVisualEffectView (effect: blur)

        addSubview(effectView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        effectView.frame = bounds
    }

}
```